# Recalculate some columns after insert on Hbase table

Tags: hadoop, hbase

Is there a simple way to recalculate some values after an insert occurs? I have a table with multiple column families, one of them statistical. I'd like to insert the original record and than have some HBase-specific facility to calculate the values offline - without blocking the insert.

Let's assume I put some files into an hbase table and want to have information about the number of lines in them and also the dates stored there.

I've been looking into RegionObserver and its preGet method. This solution works but I'm afraid it blocks the actual insert from occurring until the calculation is completed.

Answer (score 1):

use the postPut method. You can see a short introduction to HBase's coprocessors [here](https://blogs.apache.org/hbase/entry/coprocessor_introduction)

Comment: This would seem pretty obvious, however when using postPut I can't update the values that were saved. Do I need to issue another complete Put command, or just modifying the incoming Put object should suffice?

Comment: postPut (as the name implies :) ) occurs after the put so if you want to write something else you need a new one. The advantage is that it doesn't affect the latency of the original update. note that hbase is not an ACID database - it is more suitable for eventual consistency setups

Comment: Ok, I've got that - I've found an example here: http://ueshin.github.com/hbase-coprocessors/apidocs/index.html . As a side question - how can I conveniently test coprocessors? Ideally would be with unit tests. I've looked into HBase tests: src/test/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/coprocessor/TestRegionObserverStacking.java, and it shows a reasonable way to do this, but when I implement start() method the whole Zookeeper cluster is necessary, and this brings HBase, and DFS - which is heavy-weight.

Comment: Maybe you should open another q. as it is hard to paste code in comments but I use the HBaseTestingUtility . you just instantiate it and then startMiniCluster() and it sets up everything you need. If you're using maven - For the HbaseTestingUtility you need the hbase dependency with test classifier.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the classifier=tests for HBaseTestingUtility. I've created another question about the test I'm trying to write: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122247/hbase-coprocessor-unit-testing - perhaps You have some ideas about that issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try apache Pig, this is best suited for stasticl calculations and can run in local as well as mapred mode

For more detail you can visit

http://pig.apache.com

Comment: No, this is not an option. I need to use HBase.